# Flutter custom ThemeMode and font scaling Typhography.black texttheme has fontSize null

Tags: flutter, themes, typography

I'm trying to let the user choose the `ThemeMode` and font size of the app. Everything goes fine when implementing one of these features, but when I implement them both I get an exception.

My code to set the theme mode and font scale is:

```
    MaterialApp(
            title: 'Test',
            themeMode: profile.themeMode,
            theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: profile.themeColor,
                textTheme: Typography().black.apply(fontSizeFactor: profile.fontScaleFactor, fontSizeDelta: profile.fontScaleDelta),
                brightness: Brightness.light
            ),
            darkTheme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: profile.themeColor,
                textTheme: Typography().white.apply(fontSizeFactor: profile.fontScaleFactor, fontSizeDelta: profile.fontScaleDelta),
                brightness: Brightness.dark
            ),
            home: HomePage()
        ));
```

Problem is, when the user picks a font size (which sets `fontScaleFactor` and `fontScaleDelta` of the `profile` variable) I get the following exceptions (in `TextTheme.apply()`):

```
════════ (4) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════

'package:flutter/src/painting/text_style.dart': Failed assertion: line 805 pos 12: 'fontSize != null || (fontSizeFactor == 1.0 && fontSizeDelta == 0.0)': is not true.
```

Indeed, when I check, the `fontSize` of the `Typography.black` text themes is `null`, whereas the with `Theme.of(context)` it is not:

```
    print(Typography().black.title.fontSize);          //null
    print(Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.fontSize); //20
```

When I use `Theme.of(context).textTheme` instead of `Typography.black` I don't get these errors, but then the text color is not right.

I need to use my own text scaling because it will be app specific and synced between devices. Also, the users won't have access to the Android settings to change the font size of their system.

I based my code on the flutter documentation of `TextTheme` and `Typography`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Typography-class.html

[TextTheme constructor documentation:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/TextTheme.html)

```
Creates a text theme that uses the given values.

Rather than creating a new text theme, consider using Typography.black or Typography.white, which implement the typography styles in the material design specification:

material.io/design/typography/#type-scale

If you do decide to create your own text theme, consider using one of those predefined themes as a starting point for copyWith or apply.
```

[TextTheme.apply](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/apply.html)

```
Creates a copy of this text theme but with the given field replaced in each of the individual text styles.

The displayColor is applied to display4, display3, display2, display1, and caption. The bodyColor is applied to the remaining text styles.

Consider using Typography.black or Typography.white, which implement the typography styles in the material design specification, as a starting point.
```

**Flutter doctor output**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1130], locale nl-BE)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Instead of

`Typography().black.apply(...)`

use

`Theme.of(context).textTheme.merge(Typography().black).apply(...)`